# Junit testing a saveService with for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

How would I test the following code? I only know how to test the JPA part (the planDayRepo.save(planDay)).

This is the method I want to test:

```java
public String savePlans(List < PlanDay > plans) {
    for (int i = 0; i < plans.size(); i++) {
        PlanDay planDay = plans.get(i);
        long medsId = planDay.getMeds().getMedsId();
        int medsToTake = planDay.getMedsToTake();
        int pillNumber = medsRepo.getReferenceById(medsId).getPillNumber();
        int pillUpdate = pillNumber - medsToTake;
        Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.findById(medsId).get();
        if (pillUpdate > 0) {
            updatePlanDay.setPillNumber(pillUpdate);
        } else {
            return "Error: No piils available (Existing Pills: " + pillNumber + ")";
        }
        planDayRepo.save(planDay);
    }

    return "Saved Successfully";
}
```

my entities:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "meds")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "days" })
public class Meds {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long medsId;

    @Column
    private String medsName;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column
    private String category;

    @Column
    private int pillNumber;

    @Column
    private Date medsDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meds", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<PlanDay> days = new HashSet<PlanDay>();

}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "plans")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "days" })
public class Plans {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long planId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plans", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<PlanDay> days = new HashSet<PlanDay>();
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "planDay")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "planDaysId" })
public class PlanDay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long planDaysId;

    @Column
    @PastOrPresent
    @FutureOrPresent(groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    @Min(value = 2022 - 12 - 22, groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    @Max(value = 2022 - 12 - 29, groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    private Date planDate;

    @Column
    private String weekday;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "planId", nullable = false)
    private Plans plans;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "medsId", nullable = false)
    private Meds meds;

    @Column
    private int medsToTake;
}
```

an my Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/plan/save")
    public String savePlans(@RequestBody List<PlanDay> plans) {

        return saveService.savePlans(plans);
    }
```

I have  a similar loop to the deleteService and I don't know how to test that as well. The loop is how I update my pillsNumber. Would appreciate any suggestion. Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't dump us your code. Provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EasyRandom to create a list of PlanDay

```
private static final EasyRandom EASY_RANDOM = ...;
private static final List<PlanDay> playDays =
        EASY_RANDOM.objects(PlanDay.class, 10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use Mokito to mock the medRepo

```
@Mock
private MedsRepo medsRepo;

when(medsRepo.getReferencedById(anyLong()).thenReturn(...);
```

You will also need to mock PlanDayRepo for the save call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it does help, did not know about EASY_RANDOM, now I just need to test the loop in the method

Comment: @Bernardo If you feel that the answer solves your issue, a nice thing todo is to mark the answer as accepted. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more info.